# Find the probability of getting two sixes in $5$ throws of a die.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> In an experiment, a fair die is rolled until two sixes are obtained in succession. What is the probability that the experiment will end in the fifth trial?

My work:

The probability of not getting a $6$ in the first roll is $\frac{5}{6}$
Similarly for the second and third throw. Again the probability of getting a $6$ is fourth roll is $\frac{1}{6}$. So the probability of ending the game in the fifth roll is $\frac{5^3}{6^3}\times\frac{1}{6^2}=\frac{125}{6^5}$.

But the answer is not correct. Where is my mistake? Help please.

Comment: You don't account for cases such as X6X66

Comment: ok so in that case what should I calculate first? I mean should i calculate the probability of getting a 6 in first four rolls?

Comment: You need to find $P(\text{at most one of the first two rolls is a 6})\cdot P(\text{third roll is not a 6})\cdot P(\text{rolls four and five are 6}))$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X$ denote any value between $1-5$, then the optional sequences are:

- $XXX66$
- $X6X66$
- $6XX66$

Calculate the probability of each sequence:

- $P(XXX66)=\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16\cdot\frac16=\frac{5^3}{6^5}$
- $P(X6X66)=\frac56\cdot\frac16\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16\cdot\frac16=\frac{5^2}{6^5}$
- $P(6XX66)=\frac16\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16\cdot\frac16=\frac{5^2}{6^5}$

Add up the above probabilities:

$$\frac{5^3+5^2+5^2}{6^5}\approx2.25\%$$

Comment: Hi, can you also write this in two equations when including 6/6 instead?

Comment: @DavidLund: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: Something like: (5/6)*(6/6)*(5/6)*(1/6)*(1/6). 6/6 instead of 1/6.

Comment: @DavidLund: Let me get this right - you want to change $\frac16$ to $\frac66$ and keep the same result??? I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: Is there someway you can change 1/6 to 6/6, and then get the same result?

Comment: @DavidLund: I honestly don't understand your question, as well as the motivation behind it. Why do you want to replace $\frac16$ with $\frac66$, and why do you expect to get the same result after replacing $\frac16$ with $\frac66$?????

Comment: I am just wondering if you can change the equations a little bit so that you can then use 6 over 6, instead of 1/6. For no other reason, than the fact I am wondering. if it's possible to use 6 over 6 in maybe a different equation(s) instead of 1/6, and then find the answer.

Comment: @DavidLund: $\frac66=1$, so you can replace any occurrence of $1$ with $\frac66$ ($1$ as a number, not as part of another number).

Answer (score 7):

The other solutions work perfectly for a modest number of rolls.  If you were interested in a larger number, you might find a recursion helpful.

Let $P(n)$ be the probability that your game ends in exactly $n$ rolls.  Thus your problem is asking for $P(5)$.  We note that $P(1)=0,\;P(2)=\frac 1{6^2}$. For $n>2$ we remark that the first roll is either a $6$ or it isn't.  If it is, then the second roll can't be a $6$.  That leads to the recursion $$P(n)=\frac 16\times \frac 56\times P(n-2)+\frac 56\times P(n-1)$$

Very easy to implement this. As a consistency check,  we quickly get $P(5)\sim 0.022505144$ which is in line with the direct solutions.

Comment: very good approach!

Answer (score 5):

Here is simplified solution.
In order experiment to end at 5th trial, the last two rolls must be 6. So we have,
NNN66 $Pr=5^3/6^5$
6NN66  $Pr=5^2/6^5$
N6N66  $Pr=5^2/6^5$
$(N <6)$
Add all probabilities.

PS. The last two roll must be (6,6), so we get $\frac {1}{6^2}$
The third roll can't be 6, so we get $\frac {5}{6}$
And first two rolls can be anything except  (6,6), so we get $\frac {35}{6^2}$
Answer is $\frac {175}{6^5}$

Answer (score 4):

So both the fourth and the fifth rolls need to be sixes:
$$P(4^{th},5^{th}\mbox{ rolls are sixes}) = \frac{1}{6^2}$$
There are following possible combinations of rolls for the game to not end until the fifth roll:
$$(XXXOO), (XOXOO),(OXXOO)$$
where $X,O$ represent non-six and six, respectively.

Thus, the probability is:
$$P(\mbox{end in fifth trial}) = \frac{1}{6^2}\left( \frac{5^3}{6^3} +2 \cdot \frac{5^2}{6^2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \right) = \frac{175}{6^5}$$

Answer (score 3):

Condition A: The first two rolls musn't be both 6:
    $$A=1-(\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6})=\frac{35}{36}$$
Condition B: The third roll mustn't be 6:
    $$B=1-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{6}$$
Condition C: The last two rolls must be 6:
    $$C=\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$$
Probability of A, B and C being true at the same time:
    $$A\bigcup B\bigcup C=A\times B\times C=\frac{175}{6^5}=\frac{175}{7776}$$

Answer (score 0):

the odds of getting two sixes, in any order, within 6 dice (or is it die??) can be easily determined by using the binomial distribution

the odds would be 1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 ^ 4
that opening statement very simply finds the chances of getting two sixes, but there is more than one way to get two sixes, so you need to multiply that value by

2!/6!(6-2)!

goes to 15..

so 15 * 1/6 * 6 * 5/6 * 4 = about 0.2009

so basically 1/5